# reduce google datastore read operation fee

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Kind XXX_account with 1000 entities. The Kind file size is 3 mb. Whenever I send a request, the Query need to be called to find a certain entity in the Kind. Therefore, I think the google fee is almost 4 usd in just a 20 hours.

Is there anyway to reduce the datastore read operations? I plan to store 1000 entities in txt file so that I do need to read datastore everytime.

```
Datastore Read Operations       5.01 Million Ops    4.96    $0.70/ Million Ops  $3.48
```

My model.py

```
class MyUser(DatastoreUser):
    pass

class XXXAccount(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUser,
                                   collection_name='xxx_accounts')


    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    username = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    profile_url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    aaa = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    bbb = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def updateprofile(request):
    number_form = NumberForm()
    if request.method =="POST" and number_form.validate(request.form):
        acc_num_str = number_form['nb']  
        acc_num = int(acc_num_str)

        current_user = request.user
        xxx_account = current_user.xxx_accounts[acc_num] #Query
        DO SOME THING WHICH DOES NOT RELATED TO READ AND WRITE DATASTORE OPERATION
return......
```

UPDATE:

- Code was posted
- OMG, 0.32 USD for just 1000 requests.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to read all the entities just to find a single one. That's what querying is for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I upload my code. please check this line xxx_account = current_user.XXX_accounts[acc_num] #Query

Comment: I'm not able to decipher what current_user.XXX_accounts is, looks like some list of all accounts, which must have come from a query for all accounts.  You want to query for just the one account you want.

Comment: i am sorry, current_user.XXX_accounts should be current_user.xxx_accounts. xxx_accounts is a collection, so current_user.xxx_accounts is a query of XXX_accounts of user current_user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your model definition and code where you do querying entities.

Common recommendations:

If you want to find *certain* entity(ies), there is only one right way to do it - use entity key (`id` number or `key_name` string) to get it. Datastore automatically assigns some id to entity when it saves it or you can manually set some nice key_name when you're creating entity.

To get entity's id or key_name use Model.key().id() or Model.key().name() in DB or Model.key.id() in NDB.

Then you can get entity by id or key_name with [Model.get_by_id()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_id) or Model.get_by_key_name() methods if you're using old DB API or [Key.get()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities) method if you're using new NDB API. You can pass id or key_name to URL - http://example.com/getentity/[id].

Also, use Memcache to cache entities. Caching can extremely decrease using of Datastore. By the way, NDB automatically uses cache.

p.s. Sorry, I cannot post more than 2 links.

Comment: thanks, I upload my code, plz have a look. I dont get the data entity using key and id, i just pick up an entity base on it order. Plz check this line xxx_account = current_user.XXX_accounts[acc_num] #Query. I think it will use less datastore read operation. I dont know about Memcache, so maybe i wil try it. thanx

Comment: Look. As you use ReferenceProperty, you have `magic` property you called `xxx_accounts` in MyUser model. When you access this property, the [Query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling#References) object is returned. As you access this property via [], this Query is executes and returns all referenced XXXAccount entities, every request. Minimum whay you must do - it to use returned Query object more efficiently, for example - current_user.xxx_accounts.filter('some_unique_field'=acc_num).get().

Comment: Furthermore, it will be much more efficient if you store Keys of XXXAccount entities, for example, in ListProperty in MyUser model. Then you can get referenced XXXAccount entities via DB's special [db.get()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#get) function - db.get(current_user.xxx_accounts[acc_num]).

Comment: thanks. I also recognized that. I tried current_user.xxx_accounts.fetch(1, acc_num)[0], this will fetch only 1 entity at offset acc_num. But it does not help. I will try your second advice now

Comment: I cannot check now, but it seems like if you want to use fetch with offset you should use keywords arguments - fetch(limit=1,offset=acc_num).

Also keep in mind this Note from GAE [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Retrieving_Results): Note: Using an offset only avoids returning the skipped entities to your application, but these entities are still retrieved internally...and your application is billed for the read operations required to retrieve them [cutted]

Comment: current_user.xxx_accounts.filter('some_unique_field'=acc_num).get() vs XXXAccounts.get_by_key_name(keyname), please tell me which one is better in saving datastore reading operation cost. plzzz, google is making me poorer now.

Comment: "Costs for Datastore Calls" at the [Billing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing) page says that getting entity (by key) costs 1 read, querying entity costs 1 read + 1 read per entity. So XXXAccounts.get_by_key_name(keyname) is better.